# curl: Quotation character in password for basic authorization

Tags: api, curl, terminal, special-characters

I am trying to call an API with basic authorization using curl, and am facing a problem where the password contains special characters, specifically quotation mark ("). How can I send a request with such parameters?

Example:
username: myusername
password: pass"12<o

```
curl -k -u myusername:pass"12<o https://www.myurl.com/endpoint
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl -k -u 'myusername:pass"12<o' https://www.myurl.com/endpoint
```